# Sub-domain forwarding with masking via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cpanel, masking

My sub-domain `sub.domain.com` is forwarding (redirecting) to `another.website.com` correctly. However, I want to enable masking, meaning that after redirecting I want my sub-domain to show in the address bar rather than the other domain, while still showing the other domain's page content.

What should I put in the .htaccess file in order to perform this action?

Also, note that the .htaccess file is under my domain's file manager in cpanel and not subdomain's (maybe that's a given for you, but bear with my basic knowledge please...).

Should you need any more information do not hesitate to point it out please.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `mod_proxy` module, the [`ProxyPass` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [`ProxyPassReverse` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse). Put these directives in config file:

```
ProxyPass / https://another.website.com
ProxyPassReverse / https://another.website.com
```

Comment: Which config file are you referring to ? Because after a brief search online I understood that ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse can't be used in the .htaccess file

Comment: are you using a dedicated server?

Comment: Well, it's all on cpanel. I'm afraid I haven't been able to find config files... So far I've only located the .htaccess file. Do you know how to get to them ?

Comment: Ok, server is WordPress. I found a wp-config.php file on cPanel. Not sure if that's the right one, nor where to put the directives above though...

Comment: i think this might help (https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Advanced+Apache+Configuration#AdvancedApacheConfiguration-ModifyyourglobalApacheconfiguration)